# How to set a timeout to Phoenix thin driver?

Tags: timeout, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am developing a microservice with Spring Boot and using the Phoenix thin driver to query a HBase table.

I want to set the timeout to value of 2 minutes but the settings are being ignored:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put(HConstants.HBASE_RPC_TIMEOUT_KEY, "120000");
    prop.put(HConstants.HBASE_CLIENT_SCANNER_TIMEOUT_PERIOD, "120000");
    prop.put(HConstants.HBASE_RPC_READ_TIMEOUT_KEY, "120000");
    prop.put(HConstants.HBASE_CLIENT_RETRIES_NUMBER, "3");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF", prop);
```

To test this scenario I have started the Phoenix Query Server but not the HBase server. After that, I do a query to HBase through Phoenix waiting to get the timeout after the 2 minutes, but this is not happening.

**Perhaps there is a different way to timeout a Phoenix query. If so, I would greatly appreciate the suggestion.**

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

> ```
> phoenix.query.timeoutMs   Client-side property specifying the number of milliseconds after which a query will timeout on the client.
> ```
>
> Default is 10 min.    600000

```
   props.setProperty(QueryServices.THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS_ATTRIB,"600000");
```

Documented here : https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning.html

QueryServices.java is here : https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/master/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/phoenix/query/QueryServices.java

Comment: Hello Ramachandran, I have added a new question/comment to your answer. I am new here and I don't know because this is above it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ramachandran and thank you so much for your answer.

I tried your suggestion with a timeout value of 10 seconds but the timeout doesn't fire.

```
props.setProperty(QueryServices.THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS_ATTRIB,"10000");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF", props);
```

My test scenario was similar to the one described in the original question.

I think the problem is that the Phoenix Query Server keeps trying to connect to HBase for a long time and maybe that's why the driver doesn't trigger the timeout.

Perhaps some configuration is necessary on the Phoenix Query Server.

**Do you have any idea that what may be happening?**

Thank you very much for your help once again.